# C# DataGridViewRow.Selected = true not working

Tags: datagridview

I meet a problem in window programming.
We have a datagridview. Its multiselect property is set to true. the purpose is implement multiple line delete in gridview and remove them from a dictionary list. Problem is when I set the row.selected to true, it not works in second foreach loop. and during the debug, I found the Selected property of that row not change to true even though there have the dataLimits.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Selected = true; 
Code as below:

```
        private void mnuLimitsDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataLimits.SelectedCells)
            {
                 int no = int.Parse(dataLimits[0, cell.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
                 measurement.Limits.Remove(no);
                 dataLimits.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Selected = true;
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataLimits.SelectedRows)
            {
                dataLimits.Rows.Remove(row);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you had any luck solving this?  I was unable to duplicate your error.  The only visible difference in my implementation to yours was I removed the int.Parse line and replaced the next line with: 'measurement.Limits.Remove(dataLimits[0, cell.RowIndex].Value.ToString());'  Otherwise, I can only assume it's the way the source is bound, because this worked for me.

Comment: I found that if the DataGridView is not visible and has the dock setting set to 'FILL', and there is only room for one row, then the selected row will change to the first row when the grid becomes visible. I know this sounds wild but that is at least my interpretation of the problem I had.

Comment: When your datagridview is ReadOnly=true then peforming a row select programmatically doesn not work.

Answer (score 0):

DatagridVievRow can't selected if cell are selected.
Primary NEED :
dataLimits.ClearSelection();
dataLimits.CurrentCell = nullptr;
Try with this code

```
private void mnuLimitsDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRowCollection lSelectedrows = new DataGridViewRowCollection;//add list for after
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataLimits.SelectedCells)
    {
        int no = int.Parse(dataLimits[0, cell.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        measurement.Limits.Remove(no);

        lSelectedrows .Add(cell.RowIndex);//add           
    }
    dataLimits.ClearSelection();//add
    dataLimits.CurrentCell = nullptr;//add
    dataLimits.MultiSelect = true;//add need for selected rows
    dataLimits->SelectedRows = lSelectedrows ;//add
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataLimits.SelectedRows)
    {
        dataLimits.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```